# Triac flickers when I apply main power

Tags: ac, switching, esp32, triac, snubber

I am building an ESP32-based AC mains power switch by using TRIAC BT136-600D (common triac).

My first issue is my load didn't turn off the load (lamp) properly at 30%-40% brightness, and when triac triggered then the load (lamp) went to full brightness. This is my first schematic:

[image]

After I removed the load & mains input side ceramic capacitor and 5 W resistor, then the circuit worked normally. This is my second schematic:

[image]

But the issue is when I provide AC mains power to the circuit then it flickers. Like it just flashes for 200-300 milliseconds then back to normal.
If this problem remains, then my sensitive load will be damaged. And don't get confused by pin mapping my **TRIAC pin 1 = 3, 2 = 2, 3 = 1**. This is the video so you can understand what I want to say: [VIDEO](https://youtu.be/iuLFe79MOjY?si=iO9ZF65XqH3OMdu8)

Updating the new schematic:

[image]

Comment: Is your load an LED lamp?

Comment: Put the snubber across the triac (MT1 to MT2). Some current will pass through the load because of the capacitive reactance (susceptance if you want to be pedantic).

Comment: @Andyaka: No it a AC main voltage Lamp.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: I just update the Schematic, Please check my main question post.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: I don't understand the snubber circuit. I added then remove it. Without the snubber circuit system working, but it some time flicking the load output.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: I post a video link here. Please check it.

Comment: @AsifUzZaman I edited your question for grammar/readability in English. Please ensure I did not alter the meaning improperly.

Comment: @JYelton: OK, Thanks.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with triacs but am wondering why there should be a snubber across the triac anyway. As I understand it the triac will 'switch off' as soon as the current goes through zero, so there doesn't seem to be a reason to catch any inductive current during switching off as there isn't any. Or is the snubber there to protect the triac against high \$dV/dt\$?

Comment: @HarryH: I read from many blog that snubber circuit is for filter, and the triac is a based on diodes. 
but the issue is when I start or giving the AC main in or turn off the AC in , Then it flick.
You can check my video.

Comment: @AsifUzZaman What if you change the \$1k\Omega\$ resistor into something like \$300\Omega\$? As in [this circuit](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/using-a-triac-like-bta12-ot-bta08/956181). I also have no idea what pulse length your opto-coupler gives.

Comment: @HarryH: No, maybe there is need for ceramic capacitor between T1 and T2. And this is not snubber.

Comment: I see you removed the word 'snubber' from the original question. Is there any way to check whether the switching pulses coming out of the ESP are in any way synchronous with the grid voltage? Or the pulses out of the opto-coupler?

Comment: @HarryH: Please check my video. What I link pin post VIDEO. You can understand what I want to say.

Comment: Yes, I've seen the video. What I think happens is that the moment you switch the power on the lamp gives one short flash. Is there anything else that I might have missed?

Comment: Is it indeed the following circuit? [schematic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/K44jR.png)

Comment: I suggest you try the circuit from [this article](https://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/triac_principles_and_circuits_part_2).

Comment: @HarryH: Alright..... I am trying...

Comment: @HarryH: you gave me schematic in your the comment above the last comment. And I seen that, Now that mean the snubber circuit will add up with the main load live and neutral and that live will be in the triac output live.

Comment: @AsifUzZaman I'm not quite sure how to convert your comment into a circuit diagram. I was hoping you'd have seen the circuits in fig. 2, 3, 11-13, 16-18. There are no 'snubbers' in there. Could you please draw the circuit you had in mind and refer to that in a comment? My main take on those pictures is that there are a resistor and opto-triac/diac in series with the load going to the opposite terminal of the triac as where the load is connected to.